# Need git rev-parse to quietly fail and return null

Tags: git

I'm trying to find the top level of my git repo but have it fail silently if I'm currently not located in a git repo.  This code will be called from within another script where I may take the git top level or a command line option.  For example,

```
gpath = `git rev-parse --show-toplevel --quiet`
if (gpath == null) && (options.path == null) 
  puts help
end
```

If I try just the git code @ a shell prompt I get "fatal: Not a git repository".  I've tried adding the --verify switch and it yields the same result.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which shell are you scripting? Please tell me it's not (t)csh! http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt

Comment: I need to support the git command in a variety of shells.  I'm writing the current program in Ruby (but can't get the command to even run quietly in the various shells).  I'm editing the question to remove tcsh because I think it will only confuse matters (failure mode is the same in each shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if GPATH=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel --quiet 2>/dev/null`; then
  echo "repo: $GPATH"
else
  echo "not a repo"
fi
```

`2>/dev/null` will redirect the fatal error message from standard error (stderr) to /dev/null (nowhere). In that case, `git rev-parse` will exit with a failure status, which you can check using an `if` statement as above.

Answer (score 0):

Note, make sure to use Git 2.41+ (Q2 2023)

"[`git rev-parse --quiet foo@{u}`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8069aa01cd83d187813117b34ed718245d56eac9/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L118)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---quiet))</sup>", or anything that asks `@{u}` to be parsed with `GET_OID_QUIETLY` option, did not quietly fail, which has been corrected with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023).

See [commit dfbfdc5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfbfdc521daece092a599959da79c3c134f26b3c) (16 Mar 2023) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8069aa0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8069aa01cd83d187813117b34ed718245d56eac9), 28 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`object-name`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfbfdc521daece092a599959da79c3c134f26b3c): fix quiet @{u} parsing
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>

> Currently [`git` rev-parse `--quiet` @``](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dfbfdc521daece092a599959da79c3c134f26b3c/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L118)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---quiet))</sup>{u}` is not actually quiet when upstream isn't configured:
>
> ```
> fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'foo'
> ```
>
> Make it so.

You do not depend on `@{u}` in your case, but know that a `git rev-parse --quiet` was not *always* quiet.